# Select an image from a list to an image field

Tags: 7, media

I'd like to achieve the following:

When the user creates new content, instead of uploading an image to an image field every time, I would like to make an opportunity for the user to select from 8 pre-uploaded images and if none of those are appropriate, allow her/him to upload a custom image as well.

Is there any way I can achieve this with contrib modules?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try "IMCE for File Field" module for this: https://www.drupal.org/project/imce_filefield

It depends on IMCE module. Gives the option to select a file from the predefined location instead of uploading.

[image: Screenshots of IMCE for File Field]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Avatar Selection](http://drupal.org/project/avatar_selection) module?

> When a user edits their account details they can choose to upload an
>   image or photo of themselves, also known as an avatar.

**Another Hint:**
Using the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module you can allow users to select images from a library or upload there own which sounds like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach would be to use the "List" option for selecting text as a field, and in the "allowed options" put in the image tags you want.  These may or may not appear as images in the drop-down or button selector, but you can fix that in the help file or in a side block.